# Expand all nodes in infovis tree

Tags: javascript, infovis

How to expand all nodes initially in infovis tree? `constrained: false` doesn't work for me. After setting this, the space tree remains same. The space tree is displayed with root node only.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/F3fwCeG8T8o

And this,

http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Spacetree-js.html

You probably want to set parameter 'levelsToShow' to a really high number(like 100), along with 'constrained' set to false, to do the trick.